# Track object in space and time

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

I'm currently struggling to solve the following problem: The goal is determine the movement of an object by tracking an object in 2d-space and time (third dimension).

I always know the $x$ and $y$ position of said object throughout a certain time course $t$. For example:

```
t    x     y
1   1.1   0.4
2   1.2   0.5
3   1.4   0.5
...
```

Now, I'm struggling with how to determine velocity and acceleration vectors for this object in the $t$-dimension. So, I don't want to calculate these vectors given the $x,y$ information, but track this point on the t-dimension by using its velocity and acceleration vectors.

Unfortunately, this is where I'm stuck and I'd be happy about any help I can get!

Comment: Unless you have more information about the object the best you can do is estimate these things in some way. One way would be finite differences. Another would be to fit a polynomial (in $t$) to each coordinate and then use the value of velocity & acceleration implied by that model.

Comment: Another approach is to use cubic splines. These give you an acceleration that is a continuous function but may not be differentiable at some data points.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you! I guess that finite differences would be the easiest way. Accordingly, would I then compute velocity and acceleration vectors for my point at t = 2 as follows?

$$
v = (x_3,y_3 - x_1,y_1) / 2
$$

$$
a = x_3,y_3 - 2x_2,2y_2 + x_1,y_1
$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing there, I was thinking, for example, for the $x$ coordinate, that the rate of change would be ${x_{k+1}-x_k \over t_{k+1}-t_k}$, and the acceleration of the component would be similar.